# How to check if fakeAppUpdateManager is working fine?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-update, google-play-core

I am implementing In-App Updates for Android following below link:
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#java

I have implemented FakeAppUpdateManager to test the flow. But after running the app I dont see anything happening. How can I check if it is implemented correctly.

Below is the code snippet:

```java
        FakeAppUpdateManager fakeAppUpdateManager =  new FakeAppUpdateManager(this);
        fakeAppUpdateManager.setUpdateAvailable(3);
        fakeAppUpdateManager.isImmediateFlowVisible();

        assert(fakeAppUpdateManager.isConfirmationDialogVisible());

        fakeAppUpdateManager.userAcceptsUpdate();
        fakeAppUpdateManager.downloadStarts();
        fakeAppUpdateManager.downloadCompletes();

        assert( fakeAppUpdateManager.isInstallSplashScreenVisible());

        fakeAppUpdateManager.installCompletes();
```

Comment: Usually it's really useful if you can add some console output, both to confirm that the code is run, but also to get information about it's state. Best is to use a logger. Alternatively you can also use the debugger, and add a checkpoint at the relevant places in the code :) Good luck

Comment: I added some information in console and it was running. But I wanted to check if I can see something in UI